# Conversion of hexadecimal value represented as string into int in column in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, string, dataframe, data-preprocessing

I am working on a dataset where two of its attributes sport and dport have hexadecimal values such as 'Ox0303' and 'Ox5000' along with integer values. The datatype of these attributes is object type. When I am replacing these hexadecimal values with their respective decimal value in the following way:

```
df1['sport']= df1['sport'].replace(to_replace='Ox0303',value = 771, inplace=True)  
df1['sport']= df1['sport'].replace(to_replace='-1',value = 0, inplace=True)
```

it is setting the value to `None` in the dataframe.

##### sport and dport values after replacing values:

[image: sport and dport values after replacing values]

I want to set dtype of these columns  as int and to replace hexadecimal values with their respective decimal values. Pls help

Comment: Please try **not** to post [images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). (Especially not blurry images.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this dataframe:

```
          saddr   sport        daddr dport
0   192.168.1.1  0x0303  192.168.1.1    -1
1  192.168.1.10  0x0301  192.168.1.2  0xFF
2  192.168.1.20    0x03  192.168.1.3  0x01
```

The values in `sport` and `dport` columns are strings. To convert them to integers you can do:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

df["dport"] = df["dport"].apply(literal_eval)
df["sport"] = df["sport"].apply(literal_eval)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
          saddr  sport        daddr  dport
0   192.168.1.1    771  192.168.1.1     -1
1  192.168.1.10    769  192.168.1.2    255
2  192.168.1.20      3  192.168.1.3      1
```